# Whole page scrolls down by clicking link directed to inside link in iframe

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

I've a navigation bar left with some links to an iframe. This links contain inside links.

```
$("#pr1").click(function(){
    $("#content").html('<iframe id="idIframe" src="research/index.html#pr1" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="98%"></iframe>');
```

If I click on this link, it will put the id=pr1 in the source file of the iframe on top. That's fine. But not only of the iframe, but of the whole page. As the iframe is in the middle of the page the whole site scrolls down.

This happens in IE, Chrome, but not in FF. How to avoid?

EDIT
So what I want. The site should stay 'at the same place'. But the iframe should go to 'his' position.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
$("#pr1").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#content").html('<iframe id="idIframe" src="research/index.html#pr1" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="98%"></iframe>');
```